# Small size UIImageView display image becomes blurred

Tags: ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

My picture will be blurred in a small size (153x153) UIImageView, but it will be displayed normally in another large size UIImageView (375x375) page, and i load the image using sd_setImageWithURL method. I can also see this when I zoom it in Chrome, this phenomenon can be seen in pictures of clothes with stripes.

[blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkUFx.jpg)

[normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn9PG.jpg)

origin image url:
https://images.ypcang.com/2023/07/10/515264AB9DAE6B765.jpg, https://images.ypcang.com/2023/07/10/916464AB9D91234ED.jpg

How to make it display normally in small size UIImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a "Moiré pattern" or "Moiré effect" - you can read about it here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) ...

There are various things you can do to try to reduce the effect, but one easy setting may give you satisfactory results.

By default, a `UIImageView` uses "fast scaling" to get the best performance. We can change the `.minificationFilter` on the image view's layer like this:

```
imageView.layer.minificationFilter = .trilinear
```

Using your original `1200x1200` image in a `153x153` image view (which, on a `@3x` device results in a `459x459` *pixel* size), here's the difference:

[image]

Sample code to produce that (I downloaded your image and added it to assets as "sampleImage"):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let origImage = UIImage(named: "sampleImage") else {
            fatalError("Could not load test image!!!")
        }

        let v1 = UIImageView()
        let v2 = UIImageView()
        
        [v1, v2].forEach { v in
            v.image = origImage
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }

        let targetSize: CGFloat = 153.0

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            v1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: targetSize),
            v1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.widthAnchor),

            v2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.widthAnchor),
            v2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.heightAnchor),

            v1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            v2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v1.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            v1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            v2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

        ])

        // better results for bottom image view
        v2.layer.minificationFilter = .trilinear

    }
    
}
```